# How do you pass an array of multiple data types to a COM object declared as [in, out] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, com

I'm looking for help passing an object with multiple datatypes to a COM object as defined below...

This is the COM object interface:

```
[id(0x00000004), helpstring("finds the next best item")]
unsigned long GetNextItem([in, out] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) Content);
```

This is the array that needs to be passed to the COM object.

```
content[0][0] = 0.0 
content[0][1] = 1   
content[0][2] = 1   
content[0][3] = 1      
content[0][4] = -1  
content[0][5] = 0.0 
content[0][6] = 0.0
```

I have 2 issues:

1. Creating an object in C# 4.0 that can contain multiple data types.
2. Passing that object to the COM object through it's public interface.

This is the error I cannot get past:

> SafeArrayTypeMismatchException{"Specified array was not of the expected type."}

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
content[0][0] = 0.0
```

That's a jagged array, it cannot be converted to a SafeArray.  You'll need to create a multi-dimensional array instead:

```
var content = new object[42, 666];
content[0, 0] = 0.0;
```

Comment: That works for the first element, but the next 4  need to be of type integer and the last 2 of double.  What object in C# supports multiple datatypes and can be converted/passed to a safearray?